# Understanding UpdateView to change the Form and FormWidget

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I still didn't understood the UpdateView. Where does it fetch the form from?
It has exactly the fields declared in the model, but doesn't use the form defined in forms.py.

I did however follow the answer given at:

[How does one use a custom widget with a generic UpdateView without having to redefine the entire form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937076/how-does-one-use-a-custom-widget-with-a-generic-updateview-without-having-to-red)

In my case I use an IntegerField in model.py and use Radiobuttons in the Form.

So what the UpdateView does is giving me an IntegerField instead of a ChoiceField. Even when I assigned the RadioSelect Widget or a Choice Field:

The View:

```
class UpdateEinflussideen(UpdateView):

    model = Einflussideen
    EINFLUSS = [(10,'hoch'),(4,'mittel'),(1,'gering')]
    form_class = forms.models.modelform_factory(Einflussideen,
                    widgets={'einfluss': forms.ChoiceField(
                        choices=EINFLUSS, widget=forms.RadioSelect())},
                    )
    template_name = 'verbrauchererfassung/update_einflussideen.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('verbraucher')
```

The Model:

```
class Einflussideen(models.Model):

    idee = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    einfluss = models.IntegerField()
    verbraucher = models.ForeignKey(Verbraucher)
```

Comment: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.7/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in python are case-sensitive.  Change the atribute `form_Class` to the `form_class`.  Also the `widgets` argument should contain a dict with the `Widget` instances in the values:

```
form_class = forms.models.modelform_factory(Einflussideen,
                 widgets={'einfluss': forms.RadioSelect(choices=EINFLUSS)})
```

Comment: ok - that worked and lead me to 'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'needs_multipart_form' - I think this is because  The ChoiceField is a Field and not a Widget. Using just the RadioSelect gives me Just the label

Comment: You should pass the `choices` argument to the widget constructor. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works - Iam off for a walk to clear my head - freaking typos ;)